# Feynman rules for derivative couplings with identical particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, conventions, feynman-diagrams, interactions

Consider the interaction Lagrangians given by

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_1 = A_\mu \  \pi^{0} \ \partial^{\mu} \pi^{0}\\
\mathcal{L}_2 = B^{\mu\nu} \ \partial_\mu \pi^{0} \partial_{\nu} \pi^{0}\\
\mathcal{L}_3 = C_{\nu} \ \ \partial_\mu \pi^{0} \partial^\mu \pi^0 \partial^{\nu} \pi^{0} 
\end{align*}

My question concerns finding the vertex rules for the amputated diagrams corresponding to these interactions (I don't care about $A,B,C$ I just added them for Lorentz invariance).

**Notation**: I will use $\stackrel{FT}{=}$ to mean "corresponds to the momentum space interaction", and $\sim$ to mean "corresponds to the vertex rule".

---

Suppose that all the $\pi^0$ are all exiting the vertex and that $A,B,C$ are incident. We use the sign convention where the Feynman rule for outgoing momenta is $-ip_\mu$.

Then naively, we obtain (again, I don't care about $A,B,C$)

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_1 &\stackrel{FT}{=} (-ip^\pi_\mu) A^\mu \pi^0 \pi^0 \ \sim \ A^\mu (-ip^\pi_\mu) \\
\mathcal{L}_2 &\stackrel{FT}{=} (-ip^\pi_{1 \mu})(-ip^\pi_{2\nu}) B^{\mu\nu} \pi^0 \pi^0 \ \sim\  B^{\mu\nu}(-ip^\pi_{1 \mu})(-ip^\pi_{2\nu}) \\
\mathcal{L}_3 &\stackrel{FT}{=} (-ip^\pi_{1\mu})(-ip^\pi_{2\mu})(-ip^\pi_{3\nu}) C^\nu \pi^0 \pi^0 \pi^0 \ \sim \  C^\nu(-ip^\pi_{1\mu})(-ip^\pi_{2\mu})(-ip^\pi_{3\nu})
\end{align*}

**However**, since the $\pi^0$ are identical the vertex rules should be symmetric under their exchange so shouldn't momenta be symmetrized? That is, shouldn't we have that

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_1 &\sim A^\mu (-i)(p^\pi_{1\mu} + p^\pi_{2\mu}) \\
\mathcal{L}_2 &\sim B^{\mu\nu}(-i)^2\bigg[p^\pi_{1 \mu}p^\pi_{2\nu} +  p^\pi_{2 \mu} p^\pi_{1\nu}\bigg]\\
\mathcal{L}_3 & \sim C^\nu (-i)^3\bigg[ p^\pi_{1\mu}p^\pi_{2\mu} +p^\pi_{2\mu}p^\pi_{3\mu} +p^\pi_{1\mu}p^\pi_{3\mu} \bigg]\bigg[ p^\pi_{1\nu} + p^\pi_{2\nu} + p^\pi_{3\nu} \bigg]
\end{align*}

I'm about to get involved in a long, nasty computation so I just wanted to make sure.

**Additionally**, do I need to add any additional symmetry factors when performing the symmetrization of momenta? My intuition is telling me that I should add a factor $1/n!$ to $\mathcal{L}_n$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it has to be symmetrized. The general way to do this kind of thing is to go back to Wick's theorem and contractions; that also reliably pops out the normalization factor. You can find similar examples on pages 354 and 507 of Peskin.

Comment: Thanks, a bunch. Yea, I just didn't want to have to go through wick's theorem or expand the path integral. Isn't there usually a symmetry argument from which you can determine the normalization factor? Like an $S_n$ symmetry gets a $1/n!$ factor

Comment: There is, but I really think Wick's theorem is the fastest and most reliable way. Before I got used to it, I would get burned all the time trying to write it down from symmetry. For example, I _think_ your third vertex needs a $1/2$ factor, not a $1/6$ factor, because it's only the two $\phi$'s with derivatives that can be interchanged. But I wouldn't bet any money on that.

Comment: Okay, great thanks again. Guess i'll have to find the factors by hand then